# Perpendicular line through point

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to make a figure about the cathetus theorem.

This is what I got already:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,rotate=210.8]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C,5/0/A,0/3/B} 
        \tkzLabelLine[above right](A,B){$c$}
        \tkzLabelLine[below right](A,C){$b$}
        \tkzLabelLine[left](B,C){$a$}
        \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[C](180:3){D}
        \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[C](270:5){E}
        \tkzMarkRightAngle[german, size=.8](A,C,B)      
        \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
        \tkzLabelPoint(B){$B$}
        \tkzDefSquare(A,C) \tkzFillPolygon[FireBrick!70](A,C,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult) \tkzDrawPolygon(A,C,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult) 
        \tkzDefSquare(C,B) \tkzFillPolygon[Green!70](C,B,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult) \tkzDrawPolygon(C,B,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult)
        \tkzDefSquare(B,A)  \tkzGetPoints{R}{T}          
        \tkzLabelLine(B,D){$a^2$}
        \tkzLabelLine(A,E){$b^2$}
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[line width=1.25pt](A,B,C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want a line mark hight c. And rectangles below c.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing new in the code below is e.g. `\tkzDefPointBy[projection = onto A--B](C)` which lets you define a point on the line from `A` to `B`, where a normal passes through `C`. As usual, use e.g. `\tkzGetPoint{N}` to get a named coordinate.

I didn't add labels in all the rectangles, but if you want that just use the same technique as you did for the squares.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,rotate=210.8]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C,5/0/A,0/3/B} 
        \tkzLabelLine[above right](A,B){$c$}
        \tkzLabelLine[below right](A,C){$b$}
        \tkzLabelLine[left](B,C){$a$}
        \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[C](180:3){D}
        \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[C](270:5){E}
        \tkzMarkRightAngle[german, size=.8](A,C,B)      
        \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
        \tkzLabelPoint(B){$B$}
        \tkzDefSquare(A,C) \tkzFillPolygon[FireBrick!70](A,C,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult) \tkzDrawPolygon(A,C,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult) 
        \tkzDefSquare(C,B) \tkzFillPolygon[Green!70](C,B,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult) \tkzDrawPolygon(C,B,tkzFirstPointResult,tkzSecondPointResult)
        \tkzLabelLine(B,D){$a^2$}
        \tkzLabelLine(A,E){$b^2$}
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[line width=1.25pt](A,B,C)

        % bottom vertices of lower square
        \tkzDefSquare(B,A)
        \tkzGetPoints{P}{Q}
        
        % point on P-Q where the normal runs through C
        \tkzDefPointBy[projection = onto P--Q](C)
        \tkzGetPoint{M}
        % same for A-B
        \tkzDefPointBy[projection = onto A--B](C)
        \tkzGetPoint{N}

        % draw the rectangles
        \tkzFillPolygon[blue!20](A,P,M,N)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,P,M,N)
        \tkzFillPolygon[red!40](B,Q,M,N)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(B,Q,M,N)
        \tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](C,N)

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```